# Form without any style

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I would like to use `<form>` but without any style (like width, borders etc.). I need to get same effect like `<span>`. I'm using Bootstrap. Is the only valid output to be set to 0 for each css style, like width:0; etc.?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove **all** the styles from an element, just do:

```css
.element-selector {
  all: unset !important; 
}
```

Adding `!important` will not only override styles applied but also inline styles (i.e.: `<img style="width: 1000px">` has a width of 1000px set in its inline style attribute)

Comment: note that an inline `!important` would still take precedence -- e.g. this inline `width` would still take effect: `<img class="element-selector" style="width: 1000px !important">`

Comment: Yep, that's correct!

Answer (score 0):

Try using [normalize](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) to reset/clean styles

```
npm i normalize.css
```

Tip: load the module after other libs (bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

Browser defaults for `form` are already like that — no borders, margins, or padding (in other words, like an unstyled `div`, but not like a `span`, which is inline). If you're getting styles automatically applied to forms, it must be coming from somewhere in your CSS.